# How to include "" in a String in swift

Tags: swift, string

I have a really simple question and I bet the answer is as simple..

I want to create a String which include the symbol `"` twice, such as  `(Hello "" World !)` or `(Hello "new" World !)`, without breaking my String (for comprehension purpose, I've put my sentences inside of parentheses instead of said symbol `"`).

I can't remember the name of the symbol (`"`), so I can't google anything, because (`" "`) is not clear enough for searching motor..

I hope I'm being clear, thank you for your help !

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html Scroll down to the Special Characters section

Comment: Or http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_string

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: In most languages which know Unicode you'd do "“”". Curly quotes can be enclosed in straight quotes. (The heading has curly quotes but the text in the question has straight quotes.)

Comment: That character is called “quotation mark”, and a Google search for “include quotation mark in swift string” should help.

Comment: @MartinR googling quotation mark doesn't help. Check the images that it would show for that search. Btw the title of the duplicate question doesn't help either

Comment: @LeoDabus: My Google search for “include quotation mark in swift string”  immediately lead to the above duplicate, also a search for “[swift] include quotation mark in string” on this site.

Comment: @MartinR thats true but as OP mentioned in his post he didn't know how it was called

Comment: That's why I told them – as a hint for more research. It was not meant to blame OP and I did not downvote the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hashtag before and after the double quotes to allow any special character to be added inside your string:

```
let string = #"Hello "" World !"#
```